# nexus3 docker push has no blobs

Tags: docker, nexus3

I have a nexus3 and I have created a docker(host) repository

I have pushed the windows/nanoserver images to this repository

```
docker push 192.168.10.10:5000/mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809-amd64
```

I can find images ,tags and manifests of the nanoserver,

```
{
  "schemaVersion" : 1,
  "name" : "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver",
  "tag" : "1809-amd64",
  "architecture" : "amd64",
  "fsLayers" : [ {
    "blobSum" : "sha256:bc8517709e9cfff223cb034ff5be8fcbfa5409de286cdac9ae1b8878ebea6b84"
  } ],
  "history" : [ {
    "v1Compatibility" : "{\"created\":\"2021-08-05T19:15:20.6400434+00:00\",\"docker_version\":null,\"architecture\":\"amd64\",\"config\":{\"user\":\"ContainerUser\",\"cmd\":[\"c:\\\\windows\\\\system32\\\\cmd.exe\"]},\"container\":null,\"os\":\"windows\",\"container_config\":null,\"id\":\"aedc8e4fccaca21f8930881f8b7a747642598336538e85a72d7c6edfb816a58a\"}"
  } ]
}
```

But i can't find

```
sha256:bc8517709e9cfff223cb034ff5be8fcbfa5409de286cdac9ae1b8878ebea6b84
```

in nexus3 blobs

So I cannot pull nanoserver images in another computer with no internet access

```
docker pull 192.168.10.10:5000/mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809-amd64
1809-amd64: Pulling from mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver
bc8517709e9c: Retrying in 7 seconds
```

Comment: what do you mean by *no outer net*?

Comment: 。the another computer is in the LAN and cannot connect to the Internet

Comment: I see, If you delete the component and try to reupload it does it fix the issue?

Comment: I have tried it many times,it still get the same result.

Comment: What Sonatype nexus image are you using?

Comment: I run the nexus-3.33.0-01 by downloading windows archive

Comment: I happen to know that around that time nexus had a problem with docker images, could try and revert to 3.30.0-01 and check again?

Comment: I got the same result in version3.30.0-01，but i find the nanoserver mediatype is “application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.foreign.diff.tar.gzip”，it mean the image will never be pushed. how can i change the mediatype？

Comment: Personally I don't know but I think you'd benefit from asking that [here](https://community.sonatype.com/) or [here](https://gitter.im/sonatype/nexus-developers?at=5a0ccc4df257ad91099d8c73)